# Tensorflow: Filter must not be larger than the input

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, convolution

I want to perform convolution along the training sample that is of shape  [n*1] and apply zero-padding too. So far, no results.

I am building a character-level CNN (idea taken from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/skflow/text_classification_character_cnn.py))

My data is essentially tweets, initially each of length 140. 
I filter all non-alphabetical characters (replace them with empty string ''), all alphabetical characters I convert to lowercase and encode as one-hot encoder.

So I have data is n*m, where n is the number of training examples, m=140*26=3640, since each alphabetical character is encoded as one-hot vector.

Now, I am trying to perform convolution, and here is where I have a problem. Essentially:
1) I try to pad a single tweet with zeros around it. 
2) Then what I want to do is perform convolution with a filter 3*3 along the tweet, which, I expect to be of 3642*3 size, where width = 3642 and height=3 after padding.

```
F = 3 # filter size
S = 1 # stride
P = 1 # zero-pading
MAX_DOCUMENT_LENGTH = 3640
IMAGE_WIDTH = MAX_DOCUMENT_LENGTH
IMAGE_HEIGHT = 1
N_FILTERS = 20
FILTER_SHAPE1 = F
BATCH_SIZE = 257

def conv_model(X, y):
    X = tf.cast(X, tf.float32)
    y = tf.cast(y, tf.float32)
    # reshape X to 4d tensor with 2nd and 3rd dimensions being image width and height
    # final dimension being the number of color channels
    X = tf.reshape(X, [-1, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, 1])
   # first conv layer will compute N_FILTERS features for each FxF patch
    with tf.variable_scope('conv_layer1'):
            h_conv1 = tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(inputs=X,num_outputs=N_FILTERS, 
                                  kernel_size=[3,3], padding='VALID')
```

I get the error: `ValueError: Filter must not be larger than the input: Filter: (3, 3) Input: (3640, 1)`

**Why is zero-padding not applied?** At least, the result of its application does not work...

So I change the filter size to `[3,1]` and I call:

```
h_conv1 = tf.contrib.layers.conv2d(inputs=X, num_outputs=N_FILTERS, kernel_size=[3,1], padding='VALID')
```

And I don't get the error.

**Could someone please explain what is happening?**

Also, why do we need to reshape the input as X = tf.reshape(X, [-1, IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, 1])?

Answer (score 2):

> Why is zero-padding not applied?

Use `padding = 'SAME'` in conv2d for zero-padding.

> Could someone please explain what is happening?

You can't use the 3x3 filter in the case of 'flat' image. To use the 3x3 filter, input should have dimensions bigger than 3 on both width and height.

> Also, why do we need to reshape the input as X = tf.reshape(X, [-1,
>   IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT, 1])?

A Single image has a shape of [width, height, number_of_channels]. Extra dimension stands for minibatch size. -1 just preserves total size.